# Append checked checkboxes to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following situation, I have a table having rows, every row has one checkbox and other values also, if I click on checkbox the whole row should be added to the #selected-rows div using jQuery

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="test1" value=""></td>
        <td>
            Other Test1 value1
        </td>
        <td>
            Other Test1 value2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="test2" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            Other Test2 value1
        </td>
        <td>
            Other Test2 value2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="seleted-rows">

</div>
```

selected-rows div should contains all the text from table rows in which their input boxes are checked

If test1 checkbox is selected then #selected-rows will contains

```
 Other Test1 value1     Other Test1 value2
```

If both checkbox are selected then #selected-rows will be

```
 Other Test1 value1   Other Test1 value2    
 Other Test2 value1   Other Test value1
```

Comment: and the question and what have you tried?

Comment: Can you share a sample of teh content you want in teh `selected-rows`

Comment: Is this a RFP? Request for proposal?

Comment: sure,
selected-rows would be looking like this,
let if 1st checkbox is checked
then div will contains
 Other Test1 value1 Other Test1 value2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(":checkbox").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest("td").siblings("td").each(function(){
          $("#seleted-rows").append($(this).text());
        });
    }
    else {
     $("#seleted-rows").html("");
     $(":checkbox:checked").closest("td").siblings("td").each(function(){
       $("#seleted-rows").append($(this).text());
     });
    }
})
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5ryy9krn/1/)**

Comment: Thanks,This is almost near to done, but when you unchecked the checkbox the appended row does not remove.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
  var elements = $(this).parent('td').nextAll('td');
      elements.attr('select', $(this).attr('name'));
      clone =elements.clone();

  $('#seleted-rows').append(clone);
  } else
  {
      $('#seleted-rows').find('td[select="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').remove();
  }
});
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/5ryy9krn/2/

Comment: But when you unchecked the checbox the values still appending.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the easiest way to implement this is to use an onclick event.

Look here for the documentation:  https://api.jquery.com/click/

I took the liberty of giving your table an id to reference and using jQuery to simplify the JavaScript. it is unclear what exactly you would like to insert into your selected rows div.   However I believe you are looking to grab the siblings, which would look something like this:

```
$('#my-table input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         // Add the element to the div with an id identifier
         $('#selected-rows').append('<div id="[unique-id-from-input]"></div>');
         $(this).closest('td').siblings('td').each(function () {
             $('#selected-rows #[unique-id-from-input]').append($(this).clone());
         });
    } else {
         // Remove the element from the div targeted by the id identifier
         $('#selected-rows #[unique-id-from-input]').remove();
    }
});
```

The deletion process would then be much simpler, as you simply remove the div by id when the input is unchecked.

Many variations exist on this theme, and you will need to customize it to fit your exact needs, but this should be a good springboard.

Comment: Sorry for the mild typos.  Got the quotes in the right place this time.

Comment: You were right, I didn't add the div correctly.  I have edited the answer.  It is now functional and does exactly what you wanted.